# TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given) for list class inheritance

Tags: python

I searched other posts in stackoverflow and even copied them to try on my machine as answered. However, it keep failing throwing `"TypeError"`

```
# this is as one of other post in StackOverflow. 
class ListClass(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(self, *args)
        self.append('a')
        self.name = 'test'
```

I also tried empty class with pass. But, that also fails if I inherit and I guess I missed something instead of adding something more or wrong?

1) what is this `"TypeError"` and why?
2) how to fix it?

further snapshot on TypeError:

```
>>> class ListClass(list):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: Stop trying to pass all those arguments to `list()`.

Comment: Fix it by putting the three arguments in a(nother) set of parentheses, exactly the same as if you were creating a simple `list`.

Comment: can you add a call to your `ListClass` so we can get more insight on what you cant to achieve?

Answer (score 6):

You are giving it to many paramerters when you create the ListClass object, this is what you are doing:

```
s = list(2,3,3)
```

This is what you shuold be doing:

```
s = list([2,3,3])
```

Try this snippets on you interpreter.

Comment: But then what's the point of `list()`? `[1,2,3]` by itself makes me a list, so I expected `list(1,2,3)` to be the "formal" version of that. `list([1,2,3])` is just redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the tuple of arguments `args` to your instance's `extend`:

```
>>> class ListClass(list):
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...         super().__init__()
...         self.extend(args)
...         self.append('a')
...         self.name = 'test'
...
>>> ListClass(1, 2, 3)
[1, 2, 3, 'a']
```

Or pass the *unpacked* tuple of `args` to `super`'s `__init__` since `list` can be initialized with an `iterable`

```
>>> class ListClass(list):
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...         super().__init__(args) # one argument: tuple
...         self.append('a')
...         self.name = 'test'
...
>>> ListClass(1, 2, 3)
[1, 2, 3, 'a']
```

**Update:**

What you've probably done is assigning an object to the name `list`:

```
>>> list = []
>>> class ListClass(list):
...    pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: I tried your code (copied and pasted) but no luck. I guess it worked on your machine but, my machine (with python 3.4) consistently fail with the same TypeError. Not sure what is difference.

Comment: I did this on python 3.4. Restart your terminal. You've assigned a list object  to `list`. See update.